# How can i influence instance creation for annotated serializers

Tags: jackson, jackson-modules

I wrote a jackson module to enable a specific type of serialization. Now i want to enable global configuration of one of the new serializers. so i have to set a property on a serializer instance during creation.

Is there a way i can do that from within a jackson module?

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more what specifically you are trying to do?

Comment: my serializer `FubarSerializer` handles all `Fubar` instances. it can serialize these instances in two ways (A and B). i have a bunch of those Serializers wrapped into a module. i want to configure if they use A or B globaly with a setter on the module.

Answer (score 0):

Module interface is stateless, one-of-thing, so it does not have default wiring to affect things it adds.

But what you can do is to use a work-around; possibilities include:

- use of `ThreadLocal`; set before serialization, read from serializer
- use new (Jackson 2.3) feature of "attributes"; can set those for writing (`ObjectWriter.setAttribute()`) and reading (`ObjectReader.setAttribute()`), accessible by serializer/deserializer through context object (`SerializerProvider` / `DeserializationContext`)

So hopefully one of these works for your use case.